# Publisher actions not available in case feed for service console

Tags: publisher-action, casefeed, service-console

I am using the case feed in service console and only have 2 publisher actions available.

[image: only 2 publisher actions available]

When I configure the "Feed View" of this page layout, all of the options are there but the publisher actions do not display in the console.

Please help!

JD

Comment: Did you add them as quick actions in the layout itself as well? Like shown here http://i.imgur.com/dAItUJR.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually figured this one out if anyone is interested. The items you create in the case feed for Service Console can be found in the "Quick Actions" section. They must be placed into the "Quick Actions in the Salesforce Classic Publisher" section to make it into the case feed. They are not maintained or edited in the "Edit Feed View" area.

JD